# {% if v1 == v2 %} isn't working for me in Django Template where v1 is a value from a queryset and v2 is a value i get from context

Tags: django-templates

I have an Id that I pass to my template and it also loops thru a list to produce options for a select block.  I want to add selected='selected' on the value that is matching, but it looks like django templating doesn't let me compare values in an if clause.  How can I do this

I am using 1.3 and I have tried if v1 == v2 and also tried ifequal v1 v2.

```
     {% for h in hotel_list %}
     <option value="{{ h.HotelId }}" {% if h.HotelId == request.hotel_id %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ h.Title }}</option>
     --{{h.HotelId}}--{{request.hotel_id}}--
     {% endfor %}
```

This is how I call the template:

```
return render_to_response('hotels/select_hotel.html', {'hotel_list': all_hotels, 'request' : request.GET})
```

This is what I get:

```
<select id ='hotel_id' name = 'hotel_id'>


    <option value="2" >Holiday Inn</option>

    --2--7--

    <option value="3" >Joel&#39;s Inn</option>

    --3--7--

    <option value="6" >Joel&#39;s Joint</option>

    --6--7--

    <option value="1" >The Paris Hilton</option>

    --1--7--

    <option value="7" >Waldorf Astoria</option>

    --7--7--

</select>
```

Comment: I added the template snippet in question.  I'm comparing two variables not a variable with a string literal.  I wonder if that isn't allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it ends up I was comparing a string to an int.  It turns out that

```
response.GET['hotel_id']
```

is a string, so I converted to an int and passed it along in the context to my form

Answer (score 0):

Doing v1 == v2 should be correct according to the django docs.

== operator

Equality. Example:

```
{% if somevar == "x" %}
  This appears if variable somevar equals the string "x"
{% endif %}
```

I got this from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#operator

It would be easier to help if you posted your code.